# Removing document icons from a Bibtex bibliography in Beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I'm preparing a Beamer presentation that includes (on the final slide) a short bibliography in the Harvard style (agsm).  This works fine, but I find the article icons accompanying each reference annoying, especially as they are appearing behind the author name (rather than beside it).  Is there a simple way to remove the icons?

```
\begin{frame}{References}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{bibliography}{}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
```