# How do I get rid of the bullet while using /printbibliography and /footcitenote?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibliographies, footcite

I want my citations to appear in both the footnote and the endnote.For that I use the biblatex package.I am getting the citation at footnote properly but I am getting a weird bullet point while using /printbibliography.How can I get rid of that?[image]

Attached is my latex code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\tiny}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\author{Sambeet Panigrahi \& Goutham Naga Srivatsav Varanasi}
\title{Quadratic Converters}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
%\logo{} 
%\institute{} 
\date{19th August,2020} 
%\subject{} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Roadmap}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Flux Balance Principle}
Flux Balance Principle \footfullcite{nag2019theory}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\textbf{\bibname}
\printbibliography[title={References}]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{} should remove these symbols.

Comment: Thank You @leandriis.That solves it! I was able to remove the document icon using https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53127/removing-document-icons-from-a-bibtex-bibliography-in-beamer